# Custom loading message for Bootstrap table (to replace "Loading, please wait...")

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap table which can take a while to load. Currently the default message presented before the data is displayed is: "Loading, please wait..." but I'd like to change this to something more descriptive. Is it possible to change the message that is displayed inside the table whilst the data is fetched?

```js
  $('#items-table').on('load-success.bs.table', function (e) {
      if($scope.formatNoMatches == 'Loading, please wait...'){
        $scope.formatNoMatches = 'No items found';
        $('#items-table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
      }
  });
```

Comment: How are you integrating Bootstrap table with Angular -- are you using the Angular Material table `mdbTable`? Please include some code regarding how you are initializing/using the table

Comment: I've added a snippet above (as far as I can tell mdbTable is not being used here)

Comment: Ok, so is the goal to just show "no items found" in the table if the data is empty?

Comment: I'd like to be able to change the message for when the application is waiting on the http response ( with the json that holds the data that will then fill the table). Currently the message, which I believe is the default one, reads: "Loading, please wait..." but I'd like to change this to something more descriptive like: "Please wait a moment whilst the items are fetched from the database. This will take around 10 seconds"

Answer (score 1):

If you are initializing your table with jQuery, you can set the `formatLoadingMessage` property with whatever html string you'd like.

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data,
    formatLoadingMessage: function() {
        return '<b>This is a custom loading message...</b>';
    }
});
```

If you'd like, you can force when to show the message with `showLoading` and `hideLoading` as demonstrated in the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s83qgonp/

I use a setTimeout() to imitate an HTTP call/response. Credit to  http://jsfiddle.net/djhvscf/e3nk137y/4839/, which my fiddle was largely based on.

NOTE: this answer ignores the fact that the best practice is to *not* mix AngularJS and jQuery. A better approach would be to find a good AngularJS table library (perhaps ngTable http://ng-table.com/#/) and use that instead.